# Connect from Tableau Desktop to SQL Azure Data Warehouse using Active Directory Password Authentication

Tags: sql-server, tableau-api

I'm attempting to use Tableau Desktop to connect to SQL Azure Data Warehouse. The authentication method required is Active Directory Password.

I can connect just fine using a DSN-based ODBC connection in which I select the option to connect using Active Directory Password authentication ([similar situation described here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-aad-authentication-configure#active-directory-password-authentication)), but some Tableau features are not enabled via that connection method.

When I attempt to connect to `mydatawarehouse.database.windows.net,1433` via the regular Microsoft SQL Server connection in Tableau Desktop, I get an error that my credentials are incorrect using either Windows Authentication or other credentials. Running Tableau Desktop as a different user doesn't fix the situation either.

Specific error messages:

```
[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]SQL Server Network Interfaces: The Microsoft Online Services Sign-In Assistant encountered an error that might not occur if retried. Possible reasons include a transient network error. [x80048849].

[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]Cannot generate federated authentication context
```

What can I do to connect? Thanks!

Comment: Update: working with Tableau support, we have determined that Tableau does not currently support Active Directory authentication for SQL Server